# firestore cloud function update another document

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to increment the value of the field "votes" in a document (item_id) in the collection items. I want a cloud function to do this for me every time a new document is added to the collection votes. The new document contains the item_id. does anyone know how I can do this? This is what I have now:

```js
    import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
    import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
    admin.initializeApp();

    export const vote = functions.firestore.document("/Votes/{vote}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const item = context.params.item_id; 
      const itemdoc = admin.firestore().collection("items").doc(item);

      itemdoc.get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          itemdoc.update({
            "votes": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)})
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log("Error updating item vote", err);  
              });
        }
      });
    });
```

In the firebase console logs that the path must be a non-empty string. Does anyone know what I do wrong? Since the path should not be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
export const vote = functions.firestore.document("/Votes/{vote}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

        const item = snapshot.data().item_id;
        const itemDocRef = admin.firestore().collection("items").doc(item);
    
        return itemDocRef.update({
            "votes": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
        });

    });
```

---

You need to use the [`data()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html#data) method on `snapshot`, in order to get the JavaScript representation of the new document. Then you take the `item_id` property.

Another possibility is to use the [`get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html#get) method, as follows:

```
const item = snapshot.get("item_id");
```

---

I would suggest to rename the `itemdoc` variable to `itemDocRef`, since it is a [`DocumentReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html).

---

**Update following your comments:**

If you want to read the item Doc after having updated it you should do as follows:

```
export const vote = functions.firestore.document("/Votes/{vote}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        const item = snapshot.data().item_id;
        const itemDocRef = admin.firestore().collection("items").doc(item);

        await itemDocRef.update({"votes": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)});

        const itemDocSnapshot = await itemDocRef.get();

        //Do whatever you want with the Snapshot
        console.log(itemDocSnapshot.get("user_id"));
        
        // For example update another doc
        const anotherDocRef = admin.firestore().collection("....").doc("....");

        await anotherDocRef.update({"user_id": itemDocSnapshot.get("user_id")});
        
        return null;

    });
```

Note the use of the `async` and `await` keywords.

Comment: Is there also a way to request the user_id after the update? The itemrefdoc that is updated contains that user_id. Or is the only way to do it to completely load the doc like it hasn't been updated?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your exact goal. Do you mean that you want to query the document in `collection("items").doc(item)` after it has been updated? If this is what you mean, it is indeed possible. But you need to use the `get()` method, because with `update()` you don't load the doc, you just write to it.

Comment: Every write and read is billed by firebase so what I mean is after the update (that you just helped me with), which is 1 write, is it then possible to get the doc data? or should I query to document and be billed for 1 read?

Comment: I understand. I saw your updated comment not on time. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'll update my answer because it is important to correctly manage the life cycle of the Cloud Function when using asynchronous methods bac-to-back.

Comment: Great answer! This really helps me!

Answer (score 1):

```
const item = context.params.item_id;
```

By accessing `context.params`, you are trying to find a value in wildcard present in `.document("/Votes/{vote}")` which is undefined for sure. To read a field from document try this:

```
const {item_id} = snapshot.data()
// Getting item_id using Object destructuring

if (!item_id) {
  // item_id is missing in document
  return null 
}

const itemdoc = admin.firestore().collection("items").doc(item_id);
// Pass item_id in doc                                    ^^^^^^^
```

You can read more about `onCreate` in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_.documentbuilder.html#methods_1). The first parameter `snapshot` is the [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) which contains your doc data and the second parameter `context` is [EventContext](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext).