# Firebase security rule trigger (got no clue here)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I am trying to increment "numberOfEvents" field in Users collection whenever an event (in Events collection) is created. How do I do this, I know the below code is wrong I just copied it from firebase documentation. Please help.

```js
rules_version = '2';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

function increment() {
exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('Events/{docId}')
  .onCreate((change, context) => { 
  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.numberOfEvents + 1; });
}
service cloud.firestore {

  // Do not change this
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
 
     // Path to your document
     match /Users/{docId} {
     allow read;
     allow write;
     }
    match /Events/{docId} { 
      allow read;       
      allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.numberOfEvents < 16;     
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've mixed Firebase security rules with Firestore with Cloud Functions in a single code snippet, which will not work as the syntaxes are completely different.

Comment: Security rules go in the appropriate security rules file (which you can access through the web interface) and cloud functions are updated through their own special process outlined in the documentation (usually through a terminal window). You cannot mix them together in the same file.

Comment: which file does cloud functions go in, firebase.json or firestore.indexes?

Comment: Edit: I Solved it with something similar to the answer to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848968/firestore-cloud-function-update-another-document